# How to determine whether JComboBox ActionListener is triggered from code or by user

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

How can I determine whether an ActionEvent fired by a JComboBox is caused by the user from the GUI, or is caused by calling `comboBox.setSelectedItem("something")` from code? Or from any other event?

Comment: With out setting a bunch of internal flags, you can't, that's kind of the point

Comment: this making me serious problems. i am getting user messages multiple tyms

Comment: Try providing a runnable example which demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a boolean variable to keep track of when you are changing the value yourself:

```
private JComboBox<String> comboBox;
private boolean comboBoxChangedFromCode = false;
```

Set that variable while you change the value:

```
comboBoxChangedFromCode = true;
comboBox.setSelectedItem(...);
comboBoxChangedFromCode = false;
```

Check the value in your combo box's ActionListener:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (comboBoxChangedFromCode) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```